# Concurrent Futures import failed after installing it via PIP on virtual environment

Tags: python, python-2.7

Having installed with success futures on python 2.7.13, anyone wonder why it's not possible to import it ?

```
[user@server development]$ source app/bin/activate
(app) [user@server development]$ pip install futures
Requirement already satisfied: futures in ./app/lib/python2.7/site-packages
(app) [user@server development]$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 18 2017, 18:22:53)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import futures
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named futures
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried `from concurrent.futures import *`?

Comment: @Felix doesn't work too, I'm on that "but works on my machine" problem. since that error happens on the server. I'm still researching for what it could be though.

Comment: what happens if you install other packages the way you installed the `futures` package, does that work?

Comment: @Felix it only happens with futures, all others packages are being in use with success.

Comment: hmm that's weird, I'm afraid I don't know what else this could be then. Is reinstalling the virtual environment or even the python version an option?

Comment: @Felix I just tested importing futures outside of virtualenvironment and the same behaviour happens. I just found out that the Python  2.7.13 was compiled on the OS by a Junior who didn't had root access so, First i think the issue could be there. As soon i have a solution for this I'll update this question.

Comment: Try `import sys; print sys.path` and see if `./app/lib/python2.7/site-packages` is in the paths.